# How to keep https website from reloading when user hits back button?

Tags: https, security-certificate

Every time the user goes back to a page on my website in the browser it reloads.
I believe this is a result of it being an SSL site.
I have a test subdomain from the same git repo, but it is not https. It does not reload.

I think this is a terrible user experience.  Going back should be instant because it has been downloaded once already.

Both Google and Wikipedia are examples of SSL sites that do not reload when going back.

How do I achieve the same thing?

Comment: This is a coding question and off topic here but, no, it has nothing to do with being a https site. Crossing between http and https is a problem otherwise. The back button issue is a broad topic but, as I said, a coding issue. Even then it depends on the page involved.

Comment: @Rob This could simply be a caching issue, which is on-topic here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174348/will-web-browsers-cache-content-over-https may or may not be helpful. I'm sure Firefox once had a "never cache secure pages" setting, but that may no longer exist.